# Why does bower install github/repo not clone my bower.json?

Tags: bower, bower-install

When I install a library from a git repo via:

```
bower install git@github.com:fabiantheblind/p5.js.git --save
```

the component gets cloned into my `bower_components` but there is no `bower.json` in the folder. Just a `.bower.json`.

Why is that so and how can I fix this?

I also get the output:

```
bower invalid-meta  p5.js is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower invalid-meta  p5.js is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
```

But the entries are there.

(The final aim is to use grunt-wiredep to install dependencies automagically. [See my open issue here](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/104) )

Answer (score 2):

Okay. After fiddeling a bit more I got the answer:

My clone of the repo had the bower.json but I did not create a tag for it. So bower was still looking at the latest tag 0.3.6 where no bower.json was present.
By creating the tag 0.3.7 the problem is solved.